# PHP - Using http_build_query for pagination is giving me repeated parameters

Tags: php, get, pagination

I have this code for pagination

```
if($pages > 1 && $set <= $pages) {
         ?>
         <div class="pagination-bar">
         <?php
         if($set > 1) {
             ?>
             <a href="?<?php echo http_build_query($_GET); ?>&page=1">&nbsp;<<<&nbsp;</a>
             &nbsp; | &nbsp;
             <a href="?<?php echo http_build_query($_GET); ?>&page=<?php echo ((int)$set - 1) ?>"><<</a>
             &nbsp; | &nbsp;
             <?php
         }

         for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
             ?>
             <a href="?<?php echo http_build_query($_GET); ?>&page=<?php echo $i.""; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
             <?php
         }
         if($set < $pages) {
             ?>
             <a href="?<?php echo http_build_query($_GET); ?>&page=<?php echo ((int)$set + 1); ?>">>></a>
             &nbsp; | &nbsp;
             <a href="?<?php echo http_build_query($_GET); ?>&action=list&page=<?php echo $pages; ?>">&nbsp;>>>&nbsp;</a>
             <?php
         }
         ?>
        </div>
        <?php
     }
```

The pagination bar looks perfect:

1  |   2  |   3  |   4  |   >>   |    >>>

or

<<<    |   <<   |   1  |   2  |   3  |   4  |   >>   |    >>>

The problem is that (for example) when I am in the page 1...

and then I click Page 3 I get an URL LIKE THIS:

```
mypage.php?item=products&page=1&page=3
```

as you can see there are two 'page' parameters... how can I avoid this? It still works and it shows the correct page, it seems to be ignoring the first get parameter with the same name that was passed through the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_unique](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php) function

```
$_GET = array_unique ( $_GET );
```

Or better use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) function:

```
$query = http_build_query($_GET);
$query = preg_replace('/page=\d*/i', '', $query);
```

So

```
<?php
if($pages > 1 && $set <= $pages) {
     $query = http_build_query($_GET);
     $query = preg_replace('/page=\d*/i', '', $query);
     ?>
     <div class="pagination-bar">
     <?php
     if($set > 1) {
         ?>
         <a href="?<?php echo $query ?>&page=1">&nbsp;<<<&nbsp;</a>
         &nbsp; | &nbsp;
         <a href="?<?php echo $query ?>&page=<?php echo ((int)$set - 1) ?>"><<</a>
         &nbsp; | &nbsp;
         <?php
     }

     for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
         ?>
         <a href="?<?php echo $query ?>&page=<?php echo $i.""; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
         <?php
     }
     if($set < $pages) {
         ?>
         <a href="?<?php echo $query ?>&page=<?php echo ((int)$set + 1); ?>">>></a>
         &nbsp; | &nbsp;
         <a href="?<?php echo $query ?>&action=list&page=<?php echo $pages; ?>">&nbsp;>>>&nbsp;</a>
         <?php
     }
     ?>
    </div>
    <?php
 }
```

Comment: Where do I put that? can you explain me better please. Thanks for replying

Comment: Chack update, better use replace by regex in this case

Comment: Absoloutely, that seems to work! I haven't found a better solution so far. Thanks